# Redirect if authenticated, when using custom auth guards in Laravel 10

Tags: laravel, authentication

I would like to make multi authentication for my application. I have set Laravel BREEZE for the admins, but need registration/auth for the website visitors, who are for example 'fans'.
Fans are in different database table as they have more data.

I have done everyting Laravel documentation and every sources say, but it still have bugs.

1. created new Fan model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\Fansbrands;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;

class Fan extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;

    protected $guard = 'fan';

    protected $fillable = [
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'nickname',
        'email',
        'phone',
        'birthdate',
        'gender',
        'profile_img',
        'fav_driver_id',
        'fav_team_id',
        'credit',
        'country',
        'state',
        'zip',
        'city',
        'address',
        'password',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
        'password' => 'hashed',
    ];


}
```

2. Created the middleware:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class Fan
{
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (!Auth::guard('fan')->check()) {
            return redirect()->route('account-login')->with('error', 'Please login first!');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

3. Added to the kernel.php:

```
protected $middlewareAliases = [
        'fan' => \App\Http\Middleware\Fan::class,
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'auth.session' => \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'password.confirm' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\RequirePassword::class,
        'signed' => \App\Http\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
        'localization' => \App\Http\Middleware\Localization::class,
    ];
```

4. Added routes:

```
Route::middleware('guest')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/en/register', [FanController::class, 'index']);
    Route::get('/en/account-login', [FanController::class, 'create'])->name('account-login');
    Route::post('/en/account-login', [FanController::class, 'login']);
    Route::post('/en/create-account', [FanController::class, 'store']);
});

Route::prefix('en')
    ->where(['locale' => 'en'])
    ->middleware(['localization', 'fan',])
    ->group(function () {
        Route::get('/profile', [FanController::class, 'profile']);
        Route::post('/logout', [FanController::class, 'destroy'])->name('fan.logout');
    });
```

5. Created the Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Formula1;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rules;
use App\Models\Fansbrands\Fan;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class FanController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $drivers = DB::table('seasons')
            ->join('drivers', 'drivers.id', '=', 'seasons.driver_id')
            ->where('year', '=', now()->year)
            ->get();
        $teams = DB::table('seasons')
            ->join('teams', 'teams.id', '=', 'seasons.driver_id')
            ->where('year', '=', now()->year)
            ->get();
        return view('frontend.formula1.game.register')->with(compact('drivers', 'teams'));
    }

    public function profile()
    {
        return view('frontend.formula1.game.profile');
    }

    public function create()
    {

        return view('frontend.formula1.game.login');
    }

    public function login(Request $request): RedirectResponse
    {
        $credentials = $request->validate([
            'email' => ['required', 'email'],
            'password' => ['required'],
        ]);

        if (Auth::guard('fan')->attempt($credentials)) {
            $request->session()->regenerate();
            return redirect()->intended(trans('f1.locale') . '/profile');
        }

        return back()->withErrors([
            'email' => 'The provided credentials do not match our records.',
        ])->onlyInput('email');
    }

    public function store(Request $request): RedirectResponse
    {
        $birthdate = Carbon::parse($request->year . '-' . $request->month . '-' . $request->day)->format('Y-m-d');

        $request->validate([
            'first_name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'last_name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:' . Fan::class],
            'phone' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255','unique:' . Fan::class],
            'terms' => ['required'],
            'password' => ['required', Rules\Password::defaults()],
        ]);

        $fan = Fan::create([
            'first_name' => $request->first_name,
            'last_name' => $request->last_name,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'phone' => $request->phone,
            'birthdate' => $birthdate,
            'fav_driver_id' => $request->favourite_driver,
            'fav_team_id' => $request->favourite_driver,
            'password' => Hash::make($request->password),
        ]);

        Auth::guard('fan')->login($fan);

        return redirect("/{{__('f1.locale')}}/my-account");
    }

    public function destroy(Request $request): RedirectResponse
    {
        Auth::guard('fan')->logout();

        $request->session()->invalidate();

        $request->session()->regenerateToken();

        return redirect('/');
    }
}
```

6. Modified the config/auth.php:

```
'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'fan' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'fans',
        ],
    ],

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\User::class,
        ],

        'fans' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\Fansbrands\Fan::class,
        ],

    ],
```

The authentication for the fans seems to be working, but when you log in and go to a route, middlewared by the "guest" middleware, it doesn't redirect. For example you can open the registration and the login page with forms.

Also tried to modify the "guest" middleware (RedirectIfAuthenticated) but can't manage to work as expected:

(Auth::guard($guard)->check()) returns "1" if you are logged in as "admin", but returns null when you are logged in as "fan". I guess something is missing here, but don't know what.

Thank you!